# Is it possible to get pretty printing using the Chrome DevTool's Remote Debugging API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know I can debug any script using API the Chrome's [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/tot). However, I don't find all the option of the developer tools in the API. Specifically I want to do pretty printing  using Chrome's Remote Debugging Protocol API. Is it even possible? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty printing is the UI feature.
The UI part of devtools, which is actually a web page, gets the source from the inspected page and pretty print it by [JavaScriptFormatter.js](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/script_formatter_worker/JavaScriptFormatter.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

Comment: Apologies for the late accept. I had been busy for a while.